# How change django restframework JSONRenderer charset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django restframework to show my old data but inside my json are "Felipe NiÃ±o Arango" this because my data is in other charset how i can change the JSONRenderer charset

Answer (score 0):

DRF renderers use UTF-8 charset by default, however, if you need to change it, you can simply subclass your desired renderer (e.g. 
`JSONRenderer`) and set its charset as a parameter.

```
class ModifiedJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):
    charset = 'utf-8'
```

More info: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-character-set